# Crear un archivo sin reemplazar al que ya existe

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un programa en el que se realiza un proceso de compra y en el mismo al finalizar, se genera una factura con los datos de la misma. Lo que pasa es que necesito que el programa no elimine ni reemplace el archivo ya existente, si no, que cree otro archivo que como ejemplo sea:
"Factura 2.txt", Aquí dejaré la sección del código en la cual se ejecuta el proceso de creacion

```
public void CFactura(double precio, double precioIVA, double precioBol){
   Proyecto_Inventario pi = new Proyecto_Inventario();
   try {
       if(!fact.exists()){
           fact.createNewFile();

           BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fact));

           bw.write("Precio: "+(precio)+"\t"
                   +"Precio+IVA: "+(precioIVA)+"\t"
                   +"Precio Bolivares: "+(precioBol)+"\r\n");

           System.out.println("Factura creada.");

           bw.close();
           }
       }
   catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 
}
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, ¿De que tipo es la variable fact?, ¿en que momento lo inicializas? ¿en que momento cambia de valor?   ¿que es lo que hace en este momento el programa? Y aunque no tiene que ver con el problema te comento que tu método CFactura esta mal nombrado. El nombre de un método debe empezar por mayúscula y ser descriptivo (algo como creaFactura, guardaFactura, escribeFactura, etc).

Comment: Pues es una cuestión de lógica de programación para la que no hay una respuesta concreta. Tendrás que llevar un contador persistente que te diga qué número de ficheros llevas para ir incrementándolo o te tocará comprobar qué ficheros hay ya para crear el siguiente. Tu pregunta es muy general para tener una respuesta concreta.

Comment: ¿y poner un timestamp al nombre de tu archivo?, algo como `factura_20200401120000.txt` que indica que fue creado el 1ro de Abril de este año a las 12:00:00